# Implement recursive function for SQLITE database

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am syncing lat-longs from local database to the server and change the status of rows in local database table if the lat-longs are successfully synced with the server, when user presses the button.

**Problem**

When button is pressed I hit the API for syncing lat-long to the server.

1. Some long-long is missing if the internet is slow (I want to send all lat-longs in exact sequence. If miss any lat-long, I try again to send the missing).
2. If all lat-longs are successfully synced only then `EndRide Api` is called.

This is the code when the button is pressed.

```
try {
    cursor = db.getUnsyncedLatLngs(engIdForDB);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
          //calling the method to save the unsynced name to MySQL
          saveLatLngs(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(NewDatabaseForInRideData.COLUMN_ID)), cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(NewDatabaseForInRideData.Latitude)), cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(NewDatabaseForInRideData.Longitude)), engIdForDB);
         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//Problem driverEndRideAsync is called even if some LatLng skiped to upload.
driverEndRideAsync(activity, abc, abc, 0, abc);
```

And for uploading lat-long to the server

```
private void saveLatLngs(final int id, final double lati, final double longi, String engId) {

    RestClient.getApiService().update_data(abc, abc, lati, longi, String.valueOf(123), String.valueOf(123), String.valueOf(123), new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jObj;

                jObj = new JSONObject(s);
                int flag = jObj.getInt("flag");
                if (ApiResponseFlags.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG.getOrdinal() == flag) {
                    db.updateNameStatus(id, NAME_NOT_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER, engId);

                } else {
                    db.updateNameStatus(id, NAME_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER, engId);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            android.util.Log.i("update_in_ride_data", " Success =" + response);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            android.util.Log.i("update_in_ride_data", " Error =" + error);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your implementation.

- You are saving your lat-long fetched from your database table by calling an external API to your server inside a while loop. This is quite a bad implementation as this is creating a lot of `AsyncTask` in the background when you are trying to save each lat-long with an API service call.
- The cleaner implementation requires development in your backend server which should take the lat-long as a batch (i.e. a bunch of lat-long will be saved at a time). In this implementation you will be able to save your lat-long by calling the API service once, instead of having it called multiple times for each of your entries.
- Move the `driverEndRideAsync(activity, abc, abc, 0, abc);` function call inside your `try` block, so that it will not execute if you get an exception from that block while you are sending the lat-long data to your server using the API service.
- If you are keeping this exact implementation in your server side, then I would suggest you to have a background service which will check if there is any data available to be synced with server in your database table after a certain time. In that case, you will have your data synced even if you get an exception while you are syncing your data with your server, because eventually the background service will detect un-synced data and will sync them with the server application.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes it bit helpful but i want to implement this canario that i have,
explain only if some latLngs miss then how i retry to send missed LatLngs then others LatLngs and the call EndRide Api

Comment: If i get an exception how to call again EndRide Event

Comment: i already implement service to check but On EndRide button pressed i want to check and then call EndRide Api
1:-If any LatLng is missed not send next try again and after send all LatLng then call EndRide Api.